# C# - need a client - server application to share files between multiple clients - ready-made solution?

Tags: c#, database, networking

I'm developing a C# application which needs to use some kind of a database to store information. Unfortunately no DB systems such as MySQL are available so I'm limited to basic IO operations and text files. The application will run on multiple machines and all instances need access to the very same data. The solution/idea I've come up with so far is as follows:

- Client requests file from server
- Server sends the file to the client
- Client makes changes, sends back
- Server checks if in the meantime the same file was modified by another client. If yes, receive the file from the current client and merge. If not, simply replace the server's copy with the client's one

Question is: is there any ready made solution for this? Maybe I could use a framework?
If not and I have to do it myself, are there any recommendations you could give me?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are a contractor I bet the next contract will be replacing the file based solution with a database solution because it was too slow or it became quickly inconsistent. If all data is stored in one file it will be consistent but slow. If you split the data up in many small files which depend on each other you will quickly get inconsistent data if you are not careful.

Comment: No, I'm not a contractor. I'm doing this for myself (well, kind of), and the DB is not available not because someone who hired me, said so but because of the limitations/bugs of the environment I'm developing in.

Comment: It really depends how much data you need to handle and if you can live with data loss/inconsistencies. Depending on that you can design a system that is good enough or you really need to talk to the guy about requirements what they need and what constraints they think they have.

Comment: As I've said, that DB limitation cannot be *negotiated*, since a bug of my development environment prevents me from using it. Thanks for your opinion though :)

Comment: sorry for not letting it go.. but, does that include file based databases such as [Sql Server Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30709)?

Comment: It would help to tell us how much data you need to store and its structure. Besides that the bug in your development environment would be also interesting. What is it? I mean you are a developer. Go and fix the bug in your development environment.

Comment: The bug cannot be fixed as I'm not the author of the environment, neither do I have contact with the developer. The data I need to store would be a simple txt file which shouldn't exceed ~15 MB.

Comment: Depending on the frequency of writes you could use a most simple solution a full upload of the 15MB. If that is ok for you client go for it. But if you have concurrent writes you need to sort out who should win because one client will need to refresh the data and merge the changes into its UI with its own changed data. That can quickly become complex.